# How to save checkbox array value with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

In my regist form I have following checkbox

```
   <% for subject in Subject.find(:all) %>
        <%= check_box_tag "regist[subject_id][]", subject.id %>
        <%= subject.name %><br>
    <% end %>
```

here the association is

```
regist.rb
belongs_to :subject
subject.rb
has_many :regists
```

I watched railcast video for has_many through and has_and_belongs_to and I can do this using those 2 association but I need to do this for has_many association without using through.

I tried this and it show `Regist was successfully created` but only 1 is added in the table but I am sending an array of selected fields. How can save this?

Comment: Can you give us more context? I.E what your _actual_ problem is? It is it with your formatting of the checkbox, or passing the data to your models?

Comment: problem with saving the array values in database. From log I see, I get this array from checkbox "subject_id"=>["2", "3", "4", "5"] but I don't know how to save the values in database

Comment: And you're trying to save the `subject_id` to the join model?

Comment: Did you try changing subject_id to subject_ids?

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you are using this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast) ?
From what i can tell you are specifying only one subject_id instead of many subject_ids in your check_box_tag.

Try this

```
   <% for subject in Subject.find(:all) %>
        <%= check_box_tag "regist[subject_ids][]", subject.id %>
        <%= subject.name %><br>
    <% end %>
```